# XML transformation to pluck elements from multiple xmls and put in single xml

Tags: xml, xslt, mule, transformation, dataweave

I have 4 similar XML files.The only difference is the price tags.

FILE 1

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<FILE batchNo="ProductPrice_20161130120718453" changeId="1">
  <ROOT transactionNo="1">
    <PRICE docNo="1">
      <ITEMID type="1">A210BK001</ITEMID>
      <FROM_DATE>2016113012071800+0000</FROM_DATE>
      <PRICES price_band="SGD18">
        <PRODUCT_PRICE price_code="3" unit_of_sale_qty="1">333.0</PRODUCT_PRICE>
      </PRICES>
    </PRICE>
    <PRICE docNo="2">
      <ITEMID type="1">A210BK002</ITEMID>
      <FROM_DATE>2016113012071800+0000</FROM_DATE>
      <PRICES price_band="SGD18">
        <PRODUCT_PRICE price_code="3" unit_of_sale_qty="1">333.0</PRODUCT_PRICE>
      </PRICES>
    </PRICE>
  </ROOT>
  <END_OF_BATCH/>
  <END_OF_PROCESSING/>
</FILE>
```

File 2

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<FILE batchNo="ProductPrice_20161130120718453" changeId="1">
  <ROOT transactionNo="1">
    <PRICE docNo="1">
      <ITEMID type="1">A210BK001</ITEMID>
      <FROM_DATE>2016113012071800+0000</FROM_DATE>
      <PRICES price_band="USD18">
        <PRODUCT_PRICE price_code="3" unit_of_sale_qty="1">125.0</PRODUCT_PRICE>
      </PRICES>
    </PRICE>
    <PRICE docNo="2">
      <ITEMID type="1">A210BK002</ITEMID>
      <FROM_DATE>2016113012071800+0000</FROM_DATE>
      <PRICES price_band="USD18">
        <PRODUCT_PRICE price_code="3" unit_of_sale_qty="1">125.0</PRODUCT_PRICE>
      </PRICES>
    </PRICE>
  </ROOT>
  <END_OF_BATCH/>
  <END_OF_PROCESSING/>
</FILE>
```

FILE 3

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<FILE batchNo="ProductPrice_20161130120718453" changeId="1">
  <ROOT transactionNo="1">
    <PRICE docNo="1">
      <ITEMID type="1">A210BK001</ITEMID>
      <FROM_DATE>2016113012071800+0000</FROM_DATE>
      <PRICES price_band="AUD18">
        <PRODUCT_PRICE price_code="3" unit_of_sale_qty="1">175.0</PRODUCT_PRICE>
      </PRICES>
    </PRICE>
    <PRICE docNo="2">
      <ITEMID type="1">A210BK002</ITEMID>
      <FROM_DATE>2016113012071800+0000</FROM_DATE>
      <PRICES price_band="AUD18">
        <PRODUCT_PRICE price_code="3" unit_of_sale_qty="1">175.0</PRODUCT_PRICE>
      </PRICES>
    </PRICE>
  </ROOT>
  <END_OF_BATCH/>
  <END_OF_PROCESSING/>
</FILE>
```

FILE 4

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<FILE batchNo="ProductPrice_20161130120718453" changeId="1">
  <ROOT transactionNo="1">
    <PRICE docNo="1">
      <ITEMID type="1">A210BK001</ITEMID>
      <FROM_DATE>2016113012071800+0000</FROM_DATE>
      <PRICES price_band="GBP18">
        <PRODUCT_PRICE price_code="3" unit_of_sale_qty="1">90.0</PRODUCT_PRICE>
      </PRICES>
    </PRICE>
    <PRICE docNo="2">
      <ITEMID type="1">A210BK002</ITEMID>
      <FROM_DATE>2016113012071800+0000</FROM_DATE>
      <PRICES price_band="GBP18">
        <PRODUCT_PRICE price_code="3" unit_of_sale_qty="1">90.0</PRODUCT_PRICE>
      </PRICES>
    </PRICE>
  </ROOT>
  <END_OF_BATCH/>
  <END_OF_PROCESSING/>
</FILE>
```

OUTPUT FILE

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <FILE batchNo="ProductPrice_20161130120718453" changeId="1">
      <ROOT transactionNo="1">
        <PRICE docNo="1">
          <ITEMID type="1">A210BK001</ITEMID>
          <FROM_DATE>2016113012071800+0000</FROM_DATE>
          <PRICES price_band="AUD18">
            <PRODUCT_PRICE price_code="3" unit_of_sale_qty="1">175.0</PRODUCT_PRICE>
          </PRICES>
          <PRICES price_band="GBP18">
            <PRODUCT_PRICE price_code="3" unit_of_sale_qty="1">90.0</PRODUCT_PRICE>
          </PRICES>
          <PRICES price_band="SGD18">
            <PRODUCT_PRICE price_code="3" unit_of_sale_qty="1">333.0</PRODUCT_PRICE>
          </PRICES>
          <PRICES price_band="USD18">
            <PRODUCT_PRICE price_code="3" unit_of_sale_qty="1">125.0</PRODUCT_PRICE>
          </PRICES>
        </PRICE>
        <PRICE docNo="2">
          <ITEMID type="1">A210BK002</ITEMID>
          <FROM_DATE>2016113012071800+0000</FROM_DATE>
          <PRICES price_band="AUD18">
            <PRODUCT_PRICE price_code="3" unit_of_sale_qty="1">175.0</PRODUCT_PRICE>
          </PRICES>
          <PRICES price_band="GBP18">
            <PRODUCT_PRICE price_code="3" unit_of_sale_qty="1">90.0</PRODUCT_PRICE>
          </PRICES>
          <PRICES price_band="SGD18">
            <PRODUCT_PRICE price_code="3" unit_of_sale_qty="1">333.0</PRODUCT_PRICE>
          </PRICES>
          <PRICES price_band="USD18">
            <PRODUCT_PRICE price_code="3" unit_of_sale_qty="1">125.0</PRODUCT_PRICE>
          </PRICES>
        </PRICE>
      </ROOT>
      <END_OF_BATCH/>
      <END_OF_PROCESSING/>
    </FILE>
```

I want to pluck individual price bands, from these 4 different XML and coerce it into one single XML. What is the best approach to do this?

The number of such tags is >4000.

Comment: Show the XSL you have written so far

Comment: I have this transformation written in mule dataweave script. My source file is JSON the current dataweave code transforms it to the xml having all the price tags... But this is giving me GC Overhead issues. So i am trying this new approach. Havent worked with xsls.

Comment: I don't think you're using the right approach. You can't just download an XSLT processor and then ask on StackOverflow "how do I use it?". You need to do some basic reading and learning first: try some beginners' exercises from a tutorial, master the concepts of the language, then try and tackle your specific programming task, and come back here if you get stuck.

Comment: Add your current Mule flow. That helps in providing a better solution that can fit your need.